# AS3 OOP inheritance and functions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, inheritance, functional-programming

I am hoping someone could help me with a problem I am having  trying to integrate as3 code from a puzzle I have created into my game FLA file.

In Game.fla I have a main class called Engine that contains that calls a number of empty movie clips from the library to the stage and then populates each movie clip with assets from the library. Each movie clip has its own class associated with it.

I have created each puzzle in a separate file with its own main class to test and make sure the puzzles work, when I try to add the code for a puzzle to a movieclip class I am  getting a number of errors

**output error**

```
  **Warning** The linkage identifier 'feedback2' was already 
   assigned to the symbol 'wrong_box', and cannot be assigned 
    to the symbol 'graphics/scrambleAssets/wrong_box',
    since linkage identifiers must be unique.
```

**and compiler error**

```
                  Line 132 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1.
```

***line 132 is this:***

```
  if(ques_num==words.length){removeChild(checker);
  f3=new feedback3;
  addChild(f3);
   f3.x=100;
   f3.y=100;
  }else{
  getword();}
```

**Main Class**

```
      public function show_level1Puzzle(){

        level1Puzzle_screen = new level1Puzzle(this);
        remove_levelChooseBoy();

        addChild(levelPuzzleBoy_screen);
        level1Puzzle_screen.x=510;
        level1Puzzle_screen.y=380;
    }
```

** Class for level1Puzzle**

```
    package actions {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class level1Puzzle extends MovieClip {
                    public var main_class:Engine;

                    // variables used in puzzle
                   var words:Array = new Array; 
        Var rand1:int;var rand2:int; 
        var i:int; //variable used for loop iterations
        // more variables

    public function level1Puzzle(passed_class:Engine) {
                    main_class = passed_class;

    public function getword(passed_class:Engine) {
        main_class = passed_class;
        words=["cat","dog"];
        current_word=words[ques_num];
        setTiles(current_word.length);
        ques_num++;
    }
    public function setTiles(a) {tileArray=[ ];
        for(i=0;i<a;i++){
            var tempclip:Tile =new Tile;addChild(tempclip);
                tempclip.x=300+(i*180);tempclip.y=200;tempclip.tag=i;
            tempclip.original_posx=tempclip.x;
            tempclip.original_posy=tempclip.y;
            tileArray[i]=tempclip;

            var tempclip2:Placeholder =new Placeholder;addChild(tempclip2);
            tempclip2.x=300+(i*180);tempclip2.y=400;
            targetArray[i]=tempclip2;

        }//for i
        scramble_word(a);
    }
```

//MORE FUNCTIONS FOR PUZZLE

Answer (score 2):

This function has a parameter :

```
public function getword(passed_class:Engine) {
        main_class = passed_class;
        words=["cat","dog"];
        current_word=words[ques_num];
        setTiles(current_word.length);
        ques_num++;
    }
```

On line 132, you are not passing a parameter, so that is the reason for the error message.

Comment: correct, I should have explained better the parameter "checker" relates to a button, I have declared it in the Engine Class

var checker=new button_chk;
leve1Puzzle_screen.addChildAt(checker,1);

but it was throwing a undefined property error... If I declare it in the level1Puzzle class I get the same undefined property error

Comment: Line 132 1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 1. -- what I answered fixed that. This is a question and answer forum, it's not a debug your code problem by problem forum. If there is a new problem, start a new question in regards to that specific problem.